# Turning simple c algorithm into matlab

Tags: matlab

It's simple, I want to pick the biggest value of a line, make all other elements in a line equal to zero and then the position with the biggest value shall be transformed into 1.

This is the code:

```
float A [3][3];
 A [0][0] = 1.1, A [0][1] = 3.2, A [0][2] = 1.3;
 A [1][0] = 2.1, A [1][1] = 2.2, A [1][2] = 2.3;
 A [2][0] = 3.1, A [2][1] = 3.2, A [2][2] = 3.3;
for (int i=0; i<3; i++) {
  float biggest=-1000000;
  int biggest_position=0;
  for (int y=0; y<3; y++)
     if (A [i][y]>biggest) {
        biggest_position = y;
        biggest = A[i][y];
        cout << "biggest position" << biggest_position << endl;
     }   
  for (int y=0; y<3; y++)
     A [i][y] = 0;
  A [i][biggest_position] = 1;
}    
for (int i=0; i<3; i++) 
   for (int j=0; j<3; j++)
     cout << A [i][j] << endl;
```

So what I need to do to rewrite properly this code in matlab language?

Comment: Try something, then edit your question showing your Matlab code, if you're having difficulties.   It's unlikely you'll get any homework help when you haven't shown that you've attempted it!

Comment: Not a homework stuff.

Comment: As this seems a basic question to me, the [Getting Started](https://mathworks.com/help/matlab/getting-started-with-matlab.html) tutorial may be helpful for you.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `max` to find maximum, and create a all zero element matrix and put the max in first column of the matrix:

```
  newA = zeros(size(A));
  newA(:,1) = max(A,[],2);
```

Answer (score 0):

Just do:

```
A = A==max(A); %array of zeros with only ones at the maximum  of the columns of the array.
```

If  you want the maximum of a row you transpose first using a `'`

```
A = (A'==max(A'))';
```

Answer (score 0):

this may be what you want

```
a=[1,2,3;2,3,4;3,2,1;2,4,1]
[~,ap]= max(a,[],2);
atr=zeros(size(a))';
atr((1:size(a,1))*size(a,2)-size(a,2)+ap')=1;
atr'
```

and the result:

a =

```
 1     2     3
 2     3     4
 3     2     1
 2     4     1
```

ans =

```
 0     0     1
 0     0     1
 1     0     0
 0     1     0
```

it seems to be a more simple way by using matrix, you can try it